# Is there a JavaScript event to trap flex-direction change. screen onchange can't do it

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, responsive-design, dom-events

I want to give the user the option of scrolling through flex items horizontally or vertically.

The problem I have is if they change from Flex-Direction Column to row then there's now all this avaiable space on the right of the screen.

If the screen height/width/orientation changes it can be listened for but seemingly not flex-direction.

Any ideas how to resize elements aft flex direction change?

Comment: How do you give them the "*option to change flex-direction*"? If you already have code doing that, just fire an event from there as well (or directly call the "listener").

Comment: I was hoping there was something else useful between you answer and a mutation observer. Same reason we have the screen change event. you could argue that what ever changes the screen could just call you code :-(

Comment: There's a screen change event because something outside of your control (the user, the OS, the browser) changes the screen. The event is just the way for that thing to call your code. There are generally no events for changes that your code does by itself. But you haven't answered my question yet: is it *your code* that changes the flex-direction, or something else?

Comment: Yeah @Bergi you're right as I acknowledged in my first response and gve you an uptick. What I'm developing is a Module (non web-component) that has shadow DOM issues. I already accept a styleSheeet parameter that wll be adopted to th shadowRoot in a CSS Osmosis kind of way at :part and :slotted can't do it. (I can still control specificity and precednece) In this case, yes, I can offload flex-direction management to the caller. Just looking for solutions other than "Why would you possibly want to do that"

Answer (score 0):

you will definitely have to manually write the code for that as there isn't an event listener for that event (I'm not sure).

You'll have to somehow get the css flex-direction value :

```
<div id="my-div" style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;flex-align:center"></div>

var elem = document.getElementById("my-div");

var styling = elem.getAttribute("style");
```

//prop1:val;prop2:val;prop3:val;

```
var flex_prop = styling.split(";")[1];

var direction = flex_prop.split(":")[1]; //row or column

if(direction == "row" || direction == "column"){
```

//set stuff
}

or however way else you can think of getting around that.